# request in angular app returns status 400

Tags: angular, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to send a post request to an asp.net core backend in order to validate an input name, but get status 400 bad request.

This is the controller:

```
[Route("api/masterdata/general/companies")]
[ApiController]
public class CompanyController : Controller
{
    private DataContext DataContext;

    public CompanyController(DataContext dataContext)
    {
        DataContext = dataContext;
    }

    [HttpGet("{id}")]
    public Company GetCompany(long Id)
    {
        return DataContext.Companies.Find(Id);
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<Company> GetCompanies()
    {
        return DataContext.Companies;
    }

    [HttpPost("validatename/{name}")]
    public JsonResult ValidateName(string name)
    {
        IEnumerable<Company> companies = DataContext.Companies;

        bool isValid = !companies.Any(c => Common.CleanName(c.Name) == Common.CleanName(name));

        return Json(isValid);
    }
}
```

And this is the corresponding service call in the angular app:

```
  validateName(name: string): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post<boolean>("api/masterdata/general/companies/validatename/" + name, null);
  }
```

Why get I bad request? The `GetCompanies` api call is f.e. reached and working fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var cleanName=  Common.CleanName(name);
var isValid = !DataContext.Companies.Any(c => Common.CleanName(c.Name) == cleanName);
return Json(new { isValid = isValid.ToString() });
```

or better

```
return Ok( new { isValid = isValid.ToString() });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that I registered the antiforgery token feature in the `ConfigureServices` method:

```
services.AddAntiforgery(options => { options.HeaderName = "X-XSRF-TOKEN"; });
```

But I forget to add the antiforgery token to the requests coming from angular like this:

```
    app.Use(nextDelegate => context =>
    {
        string path = context.Request.Path.Value;
        string[] directUrls = { "/masterdata" };
        if (path.StartsWith("/api") || string.Equals("/", path) || directUrls.Any(url => path.StartsWith(url)))
        {
            var tokens = antiforgery.GetAndStoreTokens(context);
            context.Response.Cookies.Append("XSRF-TOKEN", tokens.RequestToken, new CookieOptions()
            {
                HttpOnly = false,
                Secure = false,
                IsEssential = true
            });
        }
        return nextDelegate(context);
    });
```

Now, it works (status 200).